# UI Automation, How to getting the underlying GUI Object?

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I am using the UI Automation(COM wrapper) framework for most of my testing but I have come to a control that I cannot see inner controls on and I do not want to do Click(60, 100) at all.

I wanted to know if there is a simple way to get the object its self,

I want to use something like Control.FromHandle() but since my app is not in the same PID as the test this returns null.

I think I might have to use injection but I dont know if I can pass the GUI object back to my main thread (from the injected one)

I believe the control is a ListBar (from infragistics) if that helps.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You can use the [NativeWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.nativewindowhandle.aspx) property to get a HWND from an AutomationElement. But it's up to you to then do more with that. If the HWND is an ActiveX control in another process, there's likely no simple way of getting at the COM object attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Brendan said, you can get then handle (HWND/IntPtr) and then use all the goodness of the Win32SDK with that handle.

I had a few scenarios myself, where e. g. certain toolbars do not expose their children through UIAutomation, but with (complicated) SDK calls, you could still get them.

Mind you, the easiest - and also pretty (though not 100%ly reliable) solution is to use screen coordinates relative to the parent control. Typically, the children do not change their position, so everything runs fine 99.99% of times.

Slightly less reliable, a lot a lot faster (a bit in runtime, a lot in development time).